# Where to put styles in a VS Project

Tags: visual-studio, css, style

I'm developing a SharePoint feature, I already know where to put custom layouts and templates, but can't find helps where to put `.css` styles.

I'm **not** asking how to reference an existing file in any (master)page, I'm looking for the correct way to add a css file in my project in order it gets deployed with the other files.

This is my Strusture:
[image]

I tried with the `Styles` folder, but during the deploy it seems to get ignored.
Where should I put my ths css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would place it under the Layouts folder.

```
Project > Layouts > [solutionname] > Styles > cssfile.css
```

[image]

By placing it here Visual Studio automatically sets the Deployment Location and Deployment Type

[image]

This article has a good approach on howto place your files. [SharePoint Farm Solution Project Structure](https://c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-farm-solution-project-structure/)

Also this article from Microsft explains how packaging and deployment works. [Package and deploy SharePoint solutions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/sharepoint/packaging-and-deploying-sharepoint-solutions)

Comment: Nice, thanks. I put the `<SharePoint:CssRegistration runat="server" name="ProjectName/cssFile.css" />` into my aspx file, no errors. However,it is not loaded...